# Removing Bright Spot and Segmenting the Gray image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I am searching for a solution for the problem I have at hand. Following is the image I have to segment in three parts:

[image]

However the problem is the bright spot in core region. I came tried to remove the bright spot by smoothing the image and getting a mask of the bright spot. then subtracting a certain value from the location of the bright spots. Here is the result:

[image]

Now when I try to segment it based on the gray value of the image then I get a weird result like the following:

[image]

I need a segmentation similar to the outlined regions of the following image:

[image]

```
clc
close all
clear
I=imread('recon-1.1-B_Export0113.tiff');
I=im2uint8(I);

filt1=ones(31)/(31^2);
I2=imfilter(I,filt1);
I2=imfilter(I2,filt1);
I2=imfilter(I2,filt1);
I2=I2-40;
% I2=imadjust(I2);

I3=I-I2;
figure, imshow(I3)
figure, imshow(I)
I4=zeros(size(I));
I4(I3>40)=1;
se = strel('disk',2);
I4=imopen(I4,se);
figure,imshow(I4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of the bright region in your image and perform binary thresholding using that interval.
Say you find the the bright region has values between t1 and t2.

> range=(I > t1 & I < t2);
>   I(range)=255;
>   I(~range)=0;

In OpenCV,cv::inRange function will make your job easier.

http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=inrange#inrange